# Не загружается картинка в UniversalImageLoader

Tags: java, android

```java
ImageView img = new ImageView(ProfileAct.this);
ImageLoader imgl = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imgl.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(null));
imgl.displayImage("http://nw.pe.hu/avatars/1.png" , img);
```

UPD:

```
public class ProfileAct extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static String Data;

public static void NmSN(String data){
    Data = data;
}


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    TextView NmSn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    try { 
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Avatar);
        ImageLoader imgl = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imgl.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ProfileAct.this));
    imgl.displayImage("http://nw.pe.hu/avatars/1.png" , img); // Запустили              асинхронный показ картинки


         // Запустили асинхронный показ картинки

    } 


    catch(Throwable e) {
        Log.e("228", e.toString(), e); }
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    // getting product details by making HTTP request





}
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top|left"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ProfileAct" >

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="4" >

    <Space />

    <Space />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Avatar"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="149dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0" />

</GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: скорее всего потому что вы контекст не передаете. `imgl.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ProfileAct.this));`

Comment: Всеравно ничего не идет

Comment: а логи как там поживают?)

Comment: Никак) Все норма

Comment: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread) только.

Comment: а попробуйте `loadImage(String uri, ImageLoadingListener listener)` этим методом загрузить картинку и в `onLoadingComplete` вручную назначить битмапу, и в дебагере посмотрите он ее выкачивает или нет

Comment: ээээ стопэ, а вы ImageView на экран атачите? создание вижу а где имейджвью дальше используется?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null

Comment: код в UPD......

Comment: у вас на экране нет ImageView с id R.id.Avatar, проверьте вашу разметку которая назначается именно в этой Activity

Comment: @Sorry Апдейтнул

Comment: а теперь убедите меня что именно этот лэяут устанавливается в качестве `setContentView` в методе `onCreate` в активити)

Comment: Сойдет?  Xml - file profile.xml  ^_^

Comment: вот с этого нужно было начинать, `setContentView(R.layout.profile);` нужно поставить после `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: на здоровье))))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.profile);` нужно поставить после `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`